# PYTHON. Как считать произвольное количество строк через input() в массив

Tags: python, массивы, строки, input

Необходимо считать несколько строк следующего формата:

```
6 4 10
4 2
2 1
4 8
6 5
1 -
7 -
```

Полученные данные необходимо записать в массив.
Написал следующий код:

```
array = []
while True:                
    x = input().split()
    if x:
        array.append(x)
    else:
        break
```

Все бы хорошо, но не проходит тестирование. поскольку требуется дополнительно ввести еще пустую строку для остановки цикла.
Как необходимо исправить код, чтоб массив формировался, сразу после ввода ПРОИЗВОЛЬНОГО количества строк? Их количества изначально неизвестно, также могут использоваться символы "-".

Comment: Список и формируется на ходу, его можно использовать на каждом обороте цикла

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Поясните подробнее.

Comment: Так и вопрос ваш не вполне ясен. Что означает - чтоб массив формировался? После каждого ввода список изменяется, он в промежуточном состоянии сформирован. Чтобы понять, что ввод закончен - нужны какие-то особые данные - или изначально знать количество строк, или признак окончания вводить

Comment: А вообще откуда задание такое? Нельзя ли привести точную формулировку и ссылку?

Comment: Попробуйте читать из `stdin`: `import sys; for line in sys.stdin: array.append(line.split())`

Comment: Тестовое задание в одну из компаний. Саму задачу я решил, но не могу пройти тест на считывание строк. Про сигнал об окончании цикла понимаю .что должно им быть не ясно. Задание решил. но не могу пройти тест. потому как требуется какой-то сигнал для окончания ввода строк.  Спецсимвол использовать нельзя, кол-во строк тоже. У меня используется пустая строка, но тогда не проходит тестирование.

Comment: Ну вот если читать из `stdin`, то отдельный сигнал об окончании не нужен будет. Там автоматом как бы `EOF` появится с окончанием потока данных и цикл `for` сам закончится. Только возможно ещё `.strip()` нужно добавить будет - на концах строк будут лишние переводы строки.